# How to hide Rectangle in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My Main report has rectangle1 which has subreport and another rectangle rectangle2 has static value.If the rectangle1 is empty then rectangle2 should not display the value.Please advice us.

Comment: You can set the visibility property of rectangle2 by specifying a specific field of rectangle1 data.

Comment: Are you hiding the rectangle1 using conditional visibility? (An expression on the Hidden property of the rectangle.)

Comment: no rectangle1 has no conditional visibility but the subreport has but the problem if rectangle1 is empty rectangle 2 should hide the static value.I have redesign my main report and place the subreport and static value in single tablix instead of rectangle.But now am struggling to hide row 2(which has static value) if row1 (which has subreport) is empty.Please help me which one is best option.

Comment: any updates on these two option